# "Reschedule to" or "reschedule for"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, to-for

> Would you like me to re-schedule **to** today instead?
>   Would you like me to re-schedule **for** today instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In American English in my experience, you schedule "on" or "for" and reschedule "for".  You *move* an appointment "to" a different day/time.

Comment: American native speaker, and I have never heard of rescheduling "on" a date. Rescheduling "for" and rescheduling "to" a date both sound normal to me, while the first sounds more formal and the latter sounds more casual.

Comment: Hmm yes, that was unclear.  You definitely *schedule* "on", but reschedule "on" is weirder.  I've heard it, but it's uncommon.

Answer (score 4):

It is more idiomatic, in American English, at least, to say *reschedule **for** today*.

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=reschedule%20for%2Creschedule%20to&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1960&year_end=2000

Comment: @Fumble, all of your points are fair. I've replaced it with a different graph.

Comment: The fact of "for" being more common is still illustrated, and I don't doubt this represents a real-world tendency. But the relative difference narrows somewhat, and I doubt there's any case for saying either is more "correct" than the other - they're just alternatives. I really don't know if such a tendency can properly be labelled "idiomatic usage".

Comment: *Reschedule for* definitely sounds better in my head.

Answer (score 2):

If you were saying scheduled, you should use "for".

Rescheduled, however, may use either "for" (which slightly emphasizes the new date) or "to" (which slightly emphasizes the fact that the time is being moved.)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the top answer (now edited). The answer is correct that you can *schedule an appointment on Tuesday* or *schedule an appointment for Tuesday*, but you can't *schedule an appointment to Tuesday* (that sounds totally wrong).

However, re-schedule is different: you can *reschedule the appointment for Tuesday* or *re-schedule the appointment to Tuesday*, but you can't *reschedule an appointment on Tuesday* (that sounds totally wrong).

In fact, **schedule on** and **reschedule to** sound the most natural to me in casual usage, whereas **schedule for** and **reschedule for** sound the most natural in a more formal, polite setting (e.g. when talking to some representative on the phone).

Answer (score -1):

Based on my research,to is correct because it tells you when the anything is meant to happen and if you say "It is scheduled for" it basically means what is about or why it is happening.